Assign DataFrame to particular cell in DataFrame
I have the case when I want to nest DataFrame into another one. The problem is, I want to handle it one by one due to the way data is populated.
Some sources of documentation recommend using an .at operator to set value of particular cell. While this works well with scalar types, it causes a problem due to that it have special logic for handling assignments of Series and DataFrames.
df.at["foo","newCol"] = DataFrame(...)

Is there any way of bypassing this logic?

I have the case when I want to nest DataFrame into another one. I suggest to rethink your approach to the solution. This is very rarely right.

@SomeDude no, thx

One possible solution can be converting the dataframe to a dictionary and then modifying the dictionary to contain the dataframes using key/index.
There is no straight-forward way to do it, it's not very optimal to do so, but if you need to do it then I think converting to dictionary->modifying dictionary-> and then again converting back to dataframe might solve your problem.

You can "cheat" pandas typing:
df.at["foo","newCol"] = (DataFrame(...))

then:
df.loc["foo", "newCol"][col_name]

will return column col_name from nested DataFrame - so you will be able to interact with it as if pd.DataFrame would be a foundational pandas dtype.

this assigns nan under the foo newCol

you need to provide representative example then - it doesn't for my dummy data. Is newCol brand new column, or does it already exist?

df = pandas.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]); df.at[1,"test"] = (pandas.DataFrame([1,2,3]))

brand new column

create column in advance and cast it to object: df.test = df.test.astype("object")

actually this will suffice df["test"] = None

It should be possible to achieve such result with following helper:
def update(frame, index, column, value):
    def applicator(row):
        if row.name == index:
            return value
        elif column in row:
            return row[column]
        else:
            return None
    frame[column] = frame.apply(applicator,axis=1)

update(df,"foo","newCol",DataFrame(...))


You can bypass it by accessing the locations using the [foo] syntax.
Let's say you make a pandas Dataframe:
df = pd.DataFrame(index=["foo"], columns=["newCol"]), then another Dataframe called nestdf:
nestdf = pd.Dataframe(...)

You can nest the nestdf in your df Dataframe with the following:
df.loc["foo", "newCol"] = nestdf

Now, we have the nestdf Dataframe that is nested within our df Dataframe.
However, this does not work for non-tuple or non-scalar data storage. In that case, you can use a dictionary, represented by {} brackets:
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': [["foo","newCol"]]})

Hope this helps!

I don't exactly understand the logic here. Can you convert the code so it will follow the example I gavE?

Yes, I adjusted it. You can use the loc feature to access the location and nest the dataframe within df

Ok, so this is exacttly the cease when loc goes brrrr, as it have special logic for assigning the Dataframes

I thought you said it had errors with the .at operator. Both the .loc and .at should work fine.

they work well for scalartypes

Try looking at this page for other functions. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html
